# opentracing: Tracing a Users Actions in the Browser

Tags: microservices, trace, opentracing

Is it possible to create a span in the browser when a user clicks on a button, and trace each call to the backend which the browser makes as a child span?

Is there a javascript library (not node.js) for open tracing, which propagates the spans from the browser to the backend services?

An example:

- The user clicks on the "do something expensive" button in the browser
- A span is created (manually I guess)
- Some business logic runs in javascript in the browser, e.g. some complex validation
- The business logic needs to make 3 calls to different microservices
- As such, three child spans are created

It should be possible to visualize the three child spans as part of the original click, which caused them.

It would be a bonus if:

- the time taken for the Javascript to run would be traced as well, in order to determine poorly performing Javascript in the browser
- it would be awesome if memory and cpu usage of the browser were also traced, but API limitations don't appear to allow this at the moment.

Comment: javascript open tracing: https://unpkg.com/@elastic/apm-rum@4.0.1/dist/bundles/elastic-apm-opentracing.umd.js